# Add item to an Array in Ruby, even if the variable does not exist

Tags: ruby, arrays, shorthand

I have the following:

```
foo ||= []
foo << "bar"
```

And I am sure this can be done in one line, I just cannot find how.

Important is, that foo may, or may not exist. If it exists it is always an Array, if it does not exist, it must become an array and get a variable appended to it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Like this:

```
(foo ||= []) << "bar"
```

The parenthesized bit returns `foo` if it already exists, or creates it if it doesn't, and then the `<<` appends to it.

Comment: This is better than my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to add `"bar"` when `foo` is not already defined:

```
foo ||= ["bar"]
```

if you want to add `"bar"` regardless of whether or not `foo` already exists:

```
(defined? foo) ? foo << "bar" : foo = ["bar"]
```

However, in the latter case, I personally prefer the way the original code is written.  Sure it can be done in one line, but I think the two line implementation is more readable.

Comment: I'm just starting to learn ruby myself, so maybe I'm missing something here, but [this doesn't seem to work for either case](http://ideone.com/Ac2fC).  In the case that foo doesn't exist, it just gets set to nil, and in the case that it does exist, nothing gets added to it.

Comment: `if (defined? foo) then foo << "bar" else foo = ["bar"] end`

Comment: @Benjamin What version of Ruby are you using? I am using JRuby 1.5.0

Comment: Ah...I needed parentheses.  Answer fixed.

Answer (score 2):

What code are you writing where you're unsure if a local variable exists?

If it's something like

```
def procedural_method(array)
  result ||= []
  array.each do |array_item|
    result << bar(array_item)
  end
  result
end
```

then you could try a more functional programming approach

```
def functional_programming_method(array)
  array.map do |array_item|
    bar(array_item)
  end
end
```

Comment: The case is: a Rails action, `FooController#create` must append items to a "global" session hash: `session[:comments] <<  id`. Not only FooController adds to that hash, but potentially others too. Now that I am writing this down, I realize a getter and setter in a helper is probably a much better pattern.